# ¿Como crear un temporizador que dure 4 horas en javascript y localStorage?

Tags: javascript

Necesito poner un temporizador que dure 4 horas en una web, ademas se necesita que en caso de que el usuario recargue la página, el temporizador continué donde se quedo, he visto varios ejemplos con plugins pero realmente no me dan el resultado esperado, ademas que siempre que recargo vuelve a comenzar el conteo.

Hasta ahora lo que he conseguido es esto(Cabe señalar que si recargo la pagina, el conteo comienza nuevamente):

```js
toHour=4;
toMinute=0;
toSecond=0;

//cuenta atras
function countDown()
{
  toSecond=toSecond-1;
  if(toSecond<0)
  {
    toSecond=59;
    toMinute=toMinute-1;
  }
  
  if(toMinute<0)
  {
    toMinute=59;
    toHour=toHour-1;
  }
  
  if(toHour<0)
  {
    $result = "00:00:00";
    document.getElementById('txtcountdown').innerHTML = $result;
  }else{
    setTimeout("countDown()",1000);
    $result = toHour + ":" + toMinute + ":" + toSecond;
    document.getElementById('txtcountdown').innerHTML = $result;
  }
}
```

```html
<body onload="countDown();">
  Tiempo restante...: 
  <p id="txtcountdown">00:00:00</p>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A continuación te dejo un ejemplo que almacena el tiempo restante en `localeStorage` y lo utiliza al carga la página en caso de existir.

```js
const countdown_time = 14400000;
const countdown_interval_time = 1000;
const countdown_key = 'countdown_time_left';
const countdown_info = document.getElementById('txtcountdown');

let countdown_interval;

function milliseconds_to_time(s) {

  function pad(n, z) {
    var z = z || 2;
    return ('00' + n).slice(-z);
  }

  var ms = s % 1000;
  s = (s - ms) / 1000;
  var secs = s % 60;
  s = (s - secs) / 60;
  var mins = s % 60;
  var hrs = (s - mins) / 60;

  return pad(hrs) + ':' + pad(mins) + ':' + pad(secs) + '.' + pad(ms, 3);

}

function countdown_interval_handler() {

  let time_left = localStorage.getItem(countdown_key) - countdown_interval_time;

  if (time_left <= 0) {
    clearInterval(countdown_interval);
    localStorage.removeItem(countdown_key);
  } else {
    localStorage.setItem(countdown_key, time_left);
  }

  countdown_info.innerHTML = milliseconds_to_time(time_left);
}

function countdown_start() {

  if (!(countdown_key in localStorage)) {
    localStorage.setItem(countdown_key, countdown_time);
  }

  countdown_interval = setInterval(countdown_interval_handler, countdown_interval_time);

}
```

```html
<body onload="countdown_start();">
  <p>Tiempo restante: <span id="txtcountdown"></span></p>
</body>
```

Comment: Excelente, muchas gracias amigo, me sirvió mucho

Comment: Excelente ejemplo, congrats, para prácticas posteriores! :)

Answer (score 0):

localStorage te sirve para almacenar los datos, sin importar incluso si cierras el navegador.

Solo modifiqué unas partes de tu código, puedes verlo funcionar.

```
<body onload="countDown();">
    <h1>Hello Plunker!</h1>
    Tiempo restante...: 
    <p id="txtcountdown">00:00:00</p>
</body>

<script>
    toHour=4;
    toMinute=0;
    toSecond=0;


    console.log(localStorage.getItem('hour'))
    console.log(localStorage.getItem('minute'))
    console.log(localStorage.getItem('second'))

    if (localStorage.getItem('second')!= null) {
    toSecond = localStorage.getItem('second')
    }

    if (localStorage.getItem('minute')!= null) {
    toMinute = localStorage.getItem('minute')
    }

    if (localStorage.getItem('hour')!= null) {
    toHour = localStorage.getItem('hour')
    }

//cuenta atras
function countDown()
{
    toSecond=toSecond-1;
    if(toSecond<0)
    {
        toSecond=59;
        toMinute=toMinute-1;        
    }

    if(toMinute<0)
    {
        toMinute=59;
        toHour=toHour-1;        
    }

    if(toHour<0)
    {
        $result = "00:00:00";
        document.getElementById('txtcountdown').innerHTML = $result;
    }else{
        setTimeout("countDown()",1000);
        localStorage.setItem('second', toSecond)
        localStorage.setItem('minute', toMinute)
        localStorage.setItem('hour', toHour)

        $result = toHour + ":" + toMinute + ":" + toSecond;
        document.getElementById('txtcountdown').innerHTML = $result;
    }
}
</script>
```

Puedes crear variables en localStorage con el método setItem

```
localStorage.setItem('nombreVariable','valorDeVariable')
```

Para obtener el valor de las variables utilizas el método getItem

```
localStorage.getItem('nombreVariable')
```

Comment: Muchas gracias amigo, lo probaré